# List of documents in 'My Personal Documents' folder

Tags: apex, document, folder

I'd like to know how I can get list of all the documents located in 'My Personal Documents' folder. For other folders I can write something like this:

> SELECT Id, Name FROM Document WHERE FolderId =: myFolderId

The problem is that I can't find out id of 'My Personal Documents' folder. Simple queries like the following doesn't help too:

> SELECT Id FROM Folder WHERE Name = 'My Personal Documents'

Answer (score 3):

```
[SELECT Id, Name FROM Document WHERE FolderId = :MYUSERID]
```

It looks like it's not really a folder... :)

Comment: This is true for all folder types-- reports, dashboards, email templates, and documents.